# Are websites that scroll up good UX?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-expectation, scrolling

I was surprised to see a website that scrolls up. [AiMEN website](http://www.aimen.io/en/) has scrolling from the bottom to top.

When I first visited it I scrolled down and nothing happened, I didn't know it scrolls up and there is no clue excerpt from three little animated dots on the top (that are small and not really a good signifier, I think).

Comment: I think this is a deliberate decision. I assume it represents ascension into the Heavens or something like that, considering the subject matter of the site. I don't think it was done purely as a usability decision. It was done *because* it is different.

Comment: You should consider using the word "signifier" instead! Don Norman popularised the term "affordance", and later coined the word "signifier" to describe something that lets the person know an affordance exists. The three dots at the top of the page are an example of this.

Comment: @JonW "ascestion into the Heavens..." - that is a good point. But still, if we are talking about websites in general, is it a good usability decision?

Comment: @AnthonyHobday , thank you, I edited the question. Now I know the difference between affordances and signifiers.

Comment: Good _usability_? No, of course not. Good _User Experience?_ Hmm, a tougher question there... they obviously did this deliberately to give the user a unique _experience_. As it is for entertainment, I think we could say that is "good".

Comment: If a) Chrome's scroll bar started at the bottom instead of the top, and b) there was a big honking arrow or text saying "scroll up", I don't see why not. I figure it's like roadworks. If convention is going to be broken, then indicate that is so clearly and make it not a misery to navigate around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Artistically, it's a fine choice, but in terms of usability, especially in the context of websites in general, it's awful. It breaks one of the usability expectations that the vast majority of users will expect, and doesn't provide any signifiers that would be recognizable to most users.